# Add comma at the end of cell in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, concatenation

I am having a excel sheet with data like below(image attached) where I am adding comma at the end of cell using concatenate formula. Formula works fine for cell with single values like `Train--> Train,` but when multiple entries are present in cell, concatenate formula is not working like `car road bus truck --> carroadbustruck,`
How can I get cell in this format `car,road,bus,truck,`

[image]

Answer (score 4):

We can use the `SUBSTITUTE()` function here along with concatenation:

```
=IF(A1<>"",SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),",")&",","")
```

This assumes that your intended logic is to replace newlines with comma, and also tag on an extra trailing comma at the end.

Comment: Thanks it worked perfectly, but it is also modifying blank cell with `,`. How can I keep blank cell as blank only.

Answer (score 4):

While `SUBSTITUTE()` will work as @Tim suggested. You can also use `TEXTSPLIT()` with `CONCAT()`.

```
=IFERROR(CONCAT(TEXTSPLIT(B1,CHAR(10))&","),"")
```

[image]